# How to delete folder from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete

I have problem with deleting a folder from Ubuntu One. I have stopped sync the folder on all of my computers connected to Ubuntu-one. But the folder all the time is in the cloud, and it's taking a lot of space. I've even erased it from disk, but it didn't help. Moreover, there is no "delete folder" button on the website (to clarify: this is not a "Ubuntu One" folder).

Comment: the service is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

I just created a folder on Ubuntu one, and was able to delete it.  Take a look at the images below for clarification.

[image]

[image]